# Levenshtein distance between each pair of elements from two large data sets

Tags: c#, performance

I am currently working on a problem to find the best matches of data in a List namely "ListA" from another List called "ListB". Whenever I find a match of an element for "ListA" with any element in "ListB" which has a confidence and accuracy with 70% or greater I add the matched string from List B and the string in List A to a tuple which I further save in a database.

Levenshtein algorithm gives me the distance between the word in ListA and words in ListB, I use the distance to calculate the similarity between the words and compare them with my threshold of 70% and if the values returned is equal or greater than the 70 percent threshold then I add the results which are either 70% or greater to the tuple.

The code that I have written for this process works fine if the records in "ListA" and "ListB" are within thousands of values and if I increase the records to a million it takes about an hour to calculate the distance for each element of the List A.

I need to optimize the process for huge data sets. Please advise where do I need to make the improvements.

My code for the process so far looks like this

```
  public static PerformFuzzyMatch()
  {
    // Fetch the ListA & List B from SQL tables
     var ListACount = await FuzzyMatchRepo.FetchListACount();
     var ListB = await FuzzyMatchRepo.FetchListBAsync();

    //Split the ListA data to smaller chunks and loop through those chunks 
     var splitGroupSize = 1000;
     var sourceDataBatchesCount = ListACount / splitGroupSize;

     // Loop through the smaller chunks of List A
     for (int b = 0; b < sourceDataBatchesCount; b++)
     {
       var currentBatchMatchedWords = new List<Tuple<string, string, double>>();
       int skipRowCount = b * splitGroupSize;
       int takeRowCount = splitGroupSize;

       // Get chunks of data from ListA according to the skipRowCount and takeRowCount
   var currentSourceDataBatch = FuzzyMatchRepository.FetchSourceDataBatch(skipRowCount, takeRowCount);

 //Loop through the ListB and parallely calculate the distance between chunks of List A and List B data
   for (int i = 0; i < ListB.Count; i++)
   {
     Parallel.For(
      0,
      currentSourceDataBatch.Count,
      new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount * 10 },
      cntr =>
      {
         try
         {
           // call the Levenshtein Algorithm to calculate the distance between each element of ListB and the smaller chunk of List A.
              int leven = LevenshteinDistance(currentSourceDataBatch[cntr], ListB[i]);
              int length = Math.Max(currentSourceDataBatch[cntr].Length, ListB[i].Length);
              double similarity = double similarity = 1.0 - (double)leven / length;
              if ((similarity * 100) >= 70)
              {                     
      currentBatchMatchedWords.Add(Tuple.Create(currentSourceDataBatch[cntr], ListB[i], similarity));
            }
          cntr++;
         }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
         exceptions.Enqueue(ex);
        }
      });
     }
   }
  }
```

And the algorithm which it calls to calculate the distance is

```
 public static int LevenshteinDistance(this string input, string comparedTo, bool caseSensitive = false)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(comparedTo))
        {
            return -1;
        }

        if (!caseSensitive)
        {
            input = Common.Hashing.InvariantUpperCaseStringExtensions.ToUpperInvariant(input);
            comparedTo = Common.Hashing.InvariantUpperCaseStringExtensions.ToUpperInvariant(comparedTo);
        }

        int inputLen = input.Length;
        int comparedToLen = comparedTo.Length;

        int[,] matrix = new int[inputLen, comparedToLen];

        //initialize           
        for (var i = 0; i < inputLen; i++)
        {
            matrix[i, 0] = i;
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < comparedToLen; i++)
        {
            matrix[0, i] = i;
        }

        //analyze
        for (var i = 1; i < inputLen; i++)
        {
            ushort si = input[i - 1];
            for (var j = 1; j < comparedToLen; j++)
            {
                ushort tj = comparedTo[j - 1];
                int cost = (si == tj) ? 0 : 1;

                int above = matrix[i - 1, j];
                int left = matrix[i, j - 1];
                int diag = matrix[i - 1, j - 1];
                int cell = FindMinimumOptimized(above + 1, left + 1, diag + cost);

                //transposition
                if (i > 1 && j > 1)
                {
                    int trans = matrix[i - 2, j - 2] + 1;
                    if (input[i - 2] != comparedTo[j - 1])
                    {
                        trans++;
                    }
                    if (input[i - 1] != comparedTo[j - 2])
                    {
                        trans++;
                    }
                    if (cell > trans)
                    {
                        cell = trans;
                    }
                }
                matrix[i, j] = cell;
            }
        }
        return matrix[inputLen - 1, comparedToLen - 1];
    }
```

Find Minimum Optimized

```
 public static int FindMinimumOptimized(int a, int b, int c)
    {
        return Math.Min(a, Math.Min(b, c));
    }
```

Comment: Please post the comple and possibly working code and example usage with sample data. Do not ommit anything like _// save the data in tuple._. It makes reviewing it impossible. Also how can we suggest anthing if you do not even post the `LevenshteinDistance`... unless it's recursive and you didn't post the signature... well just post everything and some examples or unit-tests if you have any.

Comment: thanks @t3chb0t, I have made the edits in the question.

Comment: Great! I flipped my vote ;-)

Comment: Where's the implementation of `FindMinimumOptimized`? (and `ToUpperInvariant`, for completeness sake)

Comment: Thanks @PieterWitvoet, I have edited and included it in the edit

Comment: @Shahid: thanks. It looks like there's a problem with your Levenshtein implementation though: the distance between `"a"` and `""` should be 1, not -1, and between `"abc"` and `"def"` should be 3, not 2. Also, why are you interpreting the Levenshtein distance as a similarity percentage? It's the number of differences, not a similarity rating...

Comment: @PieterWitvoet what shall I use for the similarity rating. Anyway its going to have a quadratic cost?

Comment: @Shahid: that very much depends on your requirements. Why do you need to check for similar words? What exactly does '70% similar' mean? For what purpose will the results be used?

Comment: @PieterWitvoet This is a data cleanse project where I will have a excel with company names which I have to compare against a table which contains millions of company names and the user selects a percentage of accuracy (70% is the accuracy)after which the process runs and the matched results are then stored in the database. I recently stumbled upon this algorithm which is fast but it accepts theLevenshtien distance as an input however in my code I use the distance returned from the Levenshtien algorithm and then compare it with my threshold

Comment: If '70% accurate' translates to 'a maximum edit distance of 3 per 10 characters', then you can modify your Levenshtein method to bail out as soon as it knows the edit distance will be larger than allowed for the given words. Bailing out if the word lengths differ too much could also be a useful optimization (depending on the actual data).

Comment: I would try and rework the function 'preformFuzzyMatch' to not be a double for loop. Since that makes the complexity O(n^2). If you want to go to millions then O(log(n)) would be a better option. Especially since you also have another double for each loop in the LEV function. So a bale out option as Pieter mentioned would be a good idea, like 10 characters left, 7 matched, 3 left bale out function is done. Scale from there for bigger words, like 20 characters 14 matched 0 misses bale.

Comment: The reverse to that is also true, if you are already at 4 chars out of 10 and have 3 misses then leave the function because it won't be a match. So I'd also introduce a 'miss' count and once it hits 30% or more of the word bale on the function. Any chance on sorting the list out alphabetically? Because you can probably throw out sections of the list if the first couple of letters don't match with out even going further in. Trying to think of a good way to execute this without throwing away actual 70% matches and help with optimization.

Comment: I was wondering if I have both the datasets in SQL why dont I do the Fuzzy Match there @PieterWitvoet

Comment: see also on SO: [Optimize matching elements from two large data sets using Levenshtein distance…](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54511595/optimize-matching-elements-from-two-large-data-sets-using-levenshtein-distance)

Comment: @greybeard Thanks, I had posted that question on SO :)

Comment: One advantage of starting to tackle a problem is that you find helpful questions to ask, leading to negative results (sparing time) or helpful answers: [in-set close matches](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/27555)

Comment: Having second thoughts about the origin of the `LevenshteinDistance()` implementation. Anyway, look at the terminating conditions in [A.S. Johansen's pre-2003 ("Berghel;Roach") implementation](http://web.archive.org/web/20021005221441/http://www.merriampark.com/ldcpp.htm).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(I'm tempted to comment on, I guess, program development in general or getting more out of CodeReview@SE as opposed to reviewing the code.)

- Document your code. In the code. Use what tool support you can get, for "the C-family", I use&recommend [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html).
  • Document the external/public interface:
  What is the purpose is `PerformFuzzyMatch()`? All I can see is the locally declared `currentBatchMatchedWords` growing.
  What are `FuzzyMatchRepo` and `FuzzyMatchRepository`?
  • Comment *why* everything non-trivial is there.
- going parallel seems the way to go - depending on approach, it may prove advantageous to estimate whether exchanging the roles of list A and B promises an improvement.
  The fixed group/batch size looks debatable.
- the fixed *similarity limit* looks inflexible -
  use a function as a parameter?
- computing the exact distance when interested in *similar enough* is wasteful as [commented by Pieter Witvoet](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/212823/levenshtein-distance-between-each-pair-of-elements-from-two-large-data-sets/237420#comment411891_212823)

To find solutions to evaluate, I find it useful to collect what seems helpful, with an eye on *what in the problem at hand differs from well known problems*:

- sorting the lists by length&contents allows
  • weeding out words occurring than once
  • establishing bounds on similarity
  • reusing partial results in "dynamic computation"
- character histograms help establish bounds on distance:
  sum of absolute differences is a lower bound
- the most simple part carrying information about relative position is *digram*/(ordered)*pair of characters*
- the [triangle inequality](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality) holds for the edit distances counting replacements (Hamming), insertions&deletions (Levenshtein) and *unrestricted* neighbour transpositions (unrestricted Damerau-Levenshtein - still not sure whether there is a generally accepted nomenclature)
  This is related to what ["the Wei/Chuan/Xuemin/Chengqi paper"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54511595/optimize-matching-elements-from-two-large-data-sets-using-levenshtein-distance#comment96935784_54516063) seems to exploit (from glossing that over)
- "all about a string" is in its *suffix array*
  Then, there is *FM-index* (*Fulltext-Minute-*)

---

- `LevenshteinDistance()` seems to compute the *restricted* Damerau-Levenshtein distance
  using offsets into the strings of -1 and, for transpositions, -2, which looks unusual
  ignoring last characters, which looks erroneous(, if consequential)
- it allocates an array with size the product of the lengths involved.
  Wagner-Fischer reduces this to two rows for Levenshtein; it should be easy to extend this to one more row for Damerau-Levenshtein
  reducing this by one row has been done for Levenshtein
- given an upper bound on distance (like *length of longer string*), don't compute entries that exceed that bound (*Ukkonen's optimisation* - en.wikipedia mentions single-row implementation but not this one?!).
- your code follows the mathematical presentation of the measure closely, missing to bail out early:
  if the characters match or the current character is the 2nd of a transposition, the distance does not increase, *and **no other edit costs less***

Comment: I actually managed to get the run times down by a major factor using this https://github.com/wolfgarbe/SymSpell

Comment: Update the question! Or, maybe, post your own answer.

Comment: Digram counts tell something about order and proximity, but they seem harder to "search". While sum of absolute differences of character counts sets a lower limit for distance *ld*, I'm not there with digram counts - *4ld* < accumulatedDifferences?